# iAd does not showing in apps

Tags: ios, iad

I have published 2 iOS apps few months ago. Everything was ok (iAd worked).
But last week I saw that my apps did not show iAd for no reason. 
I am looking for a solution to show iAd again. If someone has a solution...

Comment: Check iTunes Connect, there might be an update to one of the contracts you have to Agree (if you really agree) to.

Comment: I checked iTunes, but there have not an update. I have no idea why iAd is not showing in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

- Log in to itunes connect
- Agreement, tax, banking
- There will be listed any contracts that you have not agreed to yet.

Comment: I checked my contracts, but everyone are ok.